# Save an object array into one text record per array element

Tags: javascript, json, stringify

I have an application which, from time to time, saves object arrays into text files. All the elements of the object array display identical structure.

As an example, consider the following object array:

```
[{"A":1,"B":2},{"A":11,"B":22},{"A":111,"B":222}]
```

The need is to save this into a file such that it would look like this:

```
[{"A":1,"B":2} , 
{"A":11,"B":22} , 
{"A":111,"B":222}]
```

meaning, one record within the text file for each object in the array.

The reason for that is that those arrays may include hundreds and up to several thousands of elements and I wish to keep these files READABLE for humans.

Is there any trick that can be invoked when using the standard JSON.stringify method? If not, any other suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: `JSON.stringify(jsonArray).replaceAll("},{", "},\n{");`

Comment: Note: there's no such thing as a "JSON arrays" - it's either `JSON` (a string) or it's an `array` (a javascript object).   It could be a string representing an array - as you mention JSON.stringify, a *guess* would be that you have an `array` (a javascript object) and want to convert it *to* `JSON`.  Would help if you could clarify if it's starting with a string or an object/array

Comment: If you know it's always an array as the first element, you could stringify individual elements and then rebuild the array parts.  Edit: this is similar to a cut-down version of the answer that was deleted - unclear why it was deleted.   `var result = "[\n" + arr.map((e, i) => JSON.stringify(e)).join(",\n") + "\n]\n";`

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks for your comments. Though not posted along with the question, I did have the option of stringifying the JSON and then replace all appearances of `},` with `},\n`. This will do the job of course. I was just asking if there was a way to make `JSON.stringify` do the job. As per JSON-Array, you are right and I am aware of it (no such a thing). And still, it is sometimes worth exercising some flexibility to make things clear (in this case, stress that the JSON object contains a sort of a table).

Comment: The [replacer function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#replacer) sounded like an option but does not do what you need

Comment: Why not just `JSON.stringify(arr, null, 2)`? It _will_ add a line break on every object property but it's the simplest method.

Comment: @Andy, thanks for your suggestion BUT it creates one record for each element within each array element. When seeking **readability**, this is not a suitable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just stringify individual items.

```js
const data = [{"A":1,"B":2} , 
{"A":11,"B":22} , 
{"A":111,"B":222}];

let str = '[';
data.forEach((item, i) => str += (i ? ' ,\n' : '') + JSON.stringify(item));
str+=']';

console.log(str);
```

You could use `map().join()` but it's a bit slower.

```js
const data = [{"A":1,"B":2} , 
{"A":11,"B":22} , 
{"A":111,"B":222}];

const str = `[${ data.map(JSON.stringify).join(' ,\n') }]`;

console.log(str);
```

```
` Chrome/122
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>                    n=3      |      n=30       |     n=300      |    n=3000    
string concap   1.00x x1m 239 | 1.00x x100k 209 | 1.00x x10k 210 | 1.00x x1k 209
map().join()    1.05x x1m 252 | 1.10x x100k 229 | 1.10x x10k 231 | 1.15x x1k 240
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```js
const $chunk = [{"A":1,"B":2} , 
{"A":11,"B":22} , 
{"A":111,"B":222}];

const $input = [];
const data = $input;

// @benchmark string concap
let str = '[';
data.forEach((item, i) => str += (i ? ' ,\n' : '') + JSON.stringify(item));
str+=']';

// @benchmark map().join()
`[${ data.map(JSON.stringify).join(' ,\n') }]`;



/*@end*/eval(atob('e2xldCBlPWRvY3VtZW50LmJvZHkucXVlcnlTZWxlY3Rvcigic2NyaXB0Iik7aWYoIWUubWF0Y2hlcygiW2JlbmNobWFya10iKSl7bGV0IHQ9ZG9jdW1lbnQuY3JlYXRlRWxlbWVudCgic2NyaXB0Iik7dC5zcmM9Imh0dHBzOi8vY2RuLmpzZGVsaXZyLm5ldC9naC9zaWxlbnRtYW50cmEvYmVuY2htYXJrL2xvYWRlci5qcyIsdC5kZWZlcj0hMCxkb2N1bWVudC5oZWFkLmFwcGVuZENoaWxkKHQpfX0='));
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I think I'll take either the first or the second. The third is escaping the `"` character.

Answer (score 0):

While this will not give the exact result you're looking for (breaking the line for individual array elements, rather than for the whole JSON), consider taking a look into the [`space` parameter of the `JSON.stringify` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#space), which will add indentation and spacing and perhaps, will store the JSON in a more human-readable form.

Comment: Thank you r0den for your suggestion. Please refer to my comment (4th) after the original question. That solution does create the result exactly as I wanted.